# Get dynamically genrated control id within table row

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic, user-controls, row

I have web application in this am using user control to place it in the table according to row depend on count.In user control there are 4 text boxes i have placed each usercontrol within table row and given unique id to this row at page load.Problem is,when i submit form i am trying to get the data by row id but control return null.i am getting row but within that row i am not able to find control. please have look in my code if i have done any worng.

```
MasterPage ctl00 = FindControl("ctl00") as MasterPage;
ContentPlaceHolder cplacehld = ctl00.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1") as ContentPlaceHolder;
foreach (SeatBookDetails sff in SBD)
{
    TableRow trow = (TableRow)cplacehld.FindControl("Row_" + sff.SeatRowId.ToString() + "_" + sff.SeatRowno.ToString());
    if (trow != null)
    {
        string ss = trow.ID;

        TextBox txtcust = (TextBox)trow.FindControl("txtcustname");

        if (txtcust != null)
        {

      }
        TextBox txtprofession = (TextBox)trow.FindControl("txtprofession");
        if (txtprofession != null)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

When i inspect element i found structure i am attaching image of this have look.
What could be done here? How could i get this controls?

[image: Scrrenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first provide properties in you user control class having only get accessors
like:

`public string CustomerName { get { return txtCustName.Text; } }`

then you can loop through the rows and cells of the table using `foreach` loop

and then find you user control using:

`if (_control is Usercontrol)
{
 Usercontrol _form = (Usercontrol )_control;
 string name = _form.CustomerName;
}`

also make sure to load the usercontrol collections dynamically `Page_init` or `Page_Load`
to have it accessible.